# Facing error 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'cache'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am writing code to Configure the dataset for performance for CNN model. Unfortunately, I have faced an error.

My code:

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_data = train_data.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
valid_data = valid_data.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

Error: `'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'cache'`

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: In the following line 

`train_data = train_data.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)` @NicholasHunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can import your dataset with

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using `flow_from_directory` along with `ImageDataGenerator()` to set up the dataset, but they aren't compatible with `tf.data.AUTOTUNE`.
Use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` instead to load the dataset.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification